# How to keep variable from POST after a page refresh?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am receiving a var from a php page like:

```
$myId = sanitize_key( $_POST['varPostId'] );
$myId = (int) $myId;
```

That sets a query:

```
query_posts(array(
    'post__in' => array($myId)
));
```

Thing is this is an edit page, which means I will be able to change some input data on the page, but when I click the update button the page looses `$myId` and the query won't work, which means I get an empty page.

I thought to save the id in `localStorage` but I still didn't get the right logic nor I know if it's the best way. So I am looking into a php or a js solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can save it in a session variable.
That way it should be accessible ad long as the session is alive.

```
// Start session
session_start();
// Your code
$myId = sanitize_key( $_POST['varPostId'] );
$myId = (int) $myId;
// If session value exist don't do anything
// If not save $myId as session variable
if(!isset($_SESSION["myId"]))  $_SESSION["myId"] = $myId;

// Use session variable in query
query_posts(array(
'post__in' => array($_SESSION["myId"])
));
```

Just keep in mind the session_start.  It needs to be started at every page you need to access the variable.

Comment: still getting an empty page, might we quickly go to chat?

Comment: Do you use the session variable in the query? I'm using my phone and don't know how to get to chat from here. Edit: I just remembered you need to check if it's set prior to setting the session variable

Comment: what is `$_SESSION["myId"]` ? Why `myId` and not `varPostId`?

Comment: That is the session variable. You can name it whatever you want. it's an array so use it the way you want.

Comment: still a blank page, in the query i then run `'post__in' => array($myId),` is that correct or what did you mean with using the session there?

Comment: That is what I said don't use $myid in the query, use the session variable. See my update